# How can I split this into batches to avoid System.OutOfMemoryException when using large amounts of data

Tags: excel, vb.net

The following code works until I use a large number of records. Is there a way to use batches of say 1000 records at a time.

```
 Dim ws As Object = GetWorksheet(handle, workbookname, worksheetname)
 Dim origin As Object = ws.Range(cellref, cellref)
 Dim cell As Object = origin
 Dim colInd As Integer = 0, rowInd As Integer = 0 ' Offsets from the origin cell

 ' Deal with the column names first

 If includecolnames Then

     For Each col As DataColumn In Collection.Columns
         Try
             cell = origin.Offset(rowInd, colInd)
         Catch ex As Exception ' Hit the edge.
             Exit For
         End Try
         SetProperty(cell, "Value", col.ColumnName)
         colInd += 1
     Next
     rowInd += 1
 End If

 ' Now for the data itself

 For Each row As DataRow In Collection.Rows

     colInd = 0
     For Each col As DataColumn In Collection.Columns
         Try
             cell = origin.Offset(rowInd, colInd)
         Catch ex As Exception ' Hit the edge.
             Exit For
         End Try
         'MessageBox.Show("RowOffset:" & rowInd & "; ColOffset:" & colInd & "; cell: " & cell.Address(False,False))
         SetProperty(cell, "Value", row(col))
         colInd += 1
     Next

     rowInd += 1

 Next
```

As soon as I use over around 20,000 reords i get the following System.OutOfMemoryException

Comment: I think if there is a way to do this, it's going to involve (at least in part) a change in code you don't show.  You need to include the code for setting up `Collection`.

Comment: The collection comes from a 3rd party - it's basically the values from an another spreadsheet

Comment: Even so, it may be that you can rearrange your code so that you don't get all 20,000 records from it at once.  That's the first thing I would try: arrange a maximum number to try to process at once and go from there.  If getting `Collection` is all or nothing, you may be SOL (or need to go to the 3rd party for help).

Comment: @macca_big, The Collection handling is not great in BP, and that version of the VBO you have is downright awful. In any case, the Code should take a 2d array from the worksheet and then fill the DataTable with it

Comment: How megabytes big is the spreadsheet file, and how many rows and columns does it have?

Comment: I don't think you should be using Exception handling with Try/Catch. An exception is something unexpected, out of your control. Verify the value of cell to handle. This is an expected condition.